# SharePoint : Translating links for me, and its unwanted

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I am inserting a list item using sharepoint web services....

Here is my code:

```
item += @"<Field Name=""HyperLinkField"">" + this.SharePointSiteAddressLinks  + @"/lists/" + this.ListName  + @"/" + this.ID + "_" + this.MessageID + ", " + this.MessageID + ".ext</Field>";
```

the value of SharePointSiteAddressLinks is http://machineName

The list item gets inserted into the list, but the value of the hyperlink is set to http://localhost

Firstly - why does SharePoint take it apon itself to (incorrect) my links, 2ndly what can I do to turn it off?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the server, everything worked fine....